# How to parse Json from the RootObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am trying to parse JSON response so I created some classes.

Actually I want **Leg** and  **Flight** class element value. I am trying to get those element  value from **RootObject** but I don't know how to do this. I googled but I am little bit confuse.

I paste my JSON respose , Classes !!

JSON Response :

http://pastebin.com/fjjLxkd2

Classes :

```
public class Detail
{

}

  public class Airport
 {
      public string kind { get; set; }
   public string code { get; set; }
   public string city { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
    }

   public class City
  {
     public string kind { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
  public string name { get; set; }
  }

  public class Aircraft
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public string code { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}

 public class Tax
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}

  public class Carrier
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public string code { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
}

 public class Data
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public List<Airport> airport { get; set; }
public List<City> city { get; set; }
public List<Aircraft> aircraft { get; set; }
public List<Tax> tax { get; set; }
public List<Carrier> carrier { get; set; }
 }

 public class Flight
 {
public string carrier { get; set; }
public string number { get; set; }
}

 public class Leg
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string aircraft { get; set; }
public string arrivalTime { get; set; }
public string departureTime { get; set; }
public string origin { get; set; }
public string destination { get; set; }
public string originTerminal { get; set; }
public int duration { get; set; }
public int onTimePerformance { get; set; }
public int mileage { get; set; }
public string meal { get; set; }
public bool secure { get; set; }
public string destinationTerminal { get; set; }
public string operatingDisclosure { get; set; }
 }

 public class Segment
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public int duration { get; set; }
public Flight flight { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string cabin { get; set; }
public string bookingCode { get; set; }
public int bookingCodeCount { get; set; }
public string marriedSegmentGroup { get; set; }
public List<Leg> leg { get; set; }
public int connectionDuration { get; set; }
}

 public class Slouse
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public int duration { get; set; }
public List<Segment> segment { get; set; }
 }

  public class Fare
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string carrier { get; set; }
public string origin { get; set; }
public string destination { get; set; }
public string basisCode { get; set; }
 }

  public class BagDescriptor
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public string commercialName { get; set; }
public int count { get; set; }
public string subcode { get; set; }
public List<string> description { get; set; }
  }

 public class FreeBaggageOption
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public List<BagDescriptor> bagDescriptor { get; set; }
public int pieces { get; set; }
 }

 public class SegmentPricing
 {
public string kind { get; set; }
public string fareId { get; set; }
public string segmentId { get; set; }
public List<FreeBaggageOption> freeBaggageOption { get; set; }
 }

 public class Passengers
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public int adultCount { get; set; }
}

 public class Tax2
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string chargeType { get; set; }
public string code { get; set; }
public string country { get; set; }
public string salePrice { get; set; }
}

 public class Pricing
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public List<Fare> fare { get; set; }
public List<SegmentPricing> segmentPricing { get; set; }
public string baseFareTotal { get; set; }
public string saleFareTotal { get; set; }
public string saleTaxTotal { get; set; }
public string saleTotal { get; set; }
public Passengers passengers { get; set; }
public List<Tax2> tax { get; set; }
public string fareCalculation { get; set; }
public string latestTicketingTime { get; set; }
public string ptc { get; set; }
 }

 public class TripOption
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public string saleTotal { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public List<Slouse> slice { get; set; }
public List<Pricing> pricing { get; set; }
}

 public class Trips
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public string requestId { get; set; }
public Data data { get; set; }
public List<TripOption> tripOption { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
public string kind { get; set; }
public Trips trips { get; set; }
}
```

Code :

```
     var obj0 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responsedata);
```

Here I got only Trip class element . I want the Leg and Flight class element.

Comment: What do you get back when you try `obj0.trips.tripOption[0].slice[0].segment[0].leg[0]`?

Comment: It is working fine but its give only particular index data. I want whole flight leg or flight information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find information for a specific leg, you need to use `Linq` to traverse the tree. For example, if you just know the leg id, you could do something like this:

```
var allLegs = obj0.trips.tripOption.SelectMany(to => to.slice.SelectMany(sl => sl.segment.Select(sg => sg.leg)));

var leg = allLegs.FirstOrDefault(l => l.id == "yourId");
```

The query for retrieving a flight would be similar. You could also filter by `tripOption` id to get a specific `tripOption` and then retrieve flights or legs that are associated with it.